# UIButton and UIScrollView - scrolling while button pressed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button inside a scroll view. Although the view can still scroll when the button is pressed, it only happens when the user moves the scrollview quickly after clicking the button.

I have tried various gesture functions, but I note that the button does not seem to activate any gesture functions. The button only activates touch functions.

How can the scrollview recapture the gesture once ios engages the button down?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your code:

```
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = true
```

You can also set it in storyboard

You also need to add:

```
override func touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view: UIView) -> Bool { 
    if view.isKindOfClass(UIButton) { return true } 
    return super.touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mika. Your suggestion worked when I added this in the custom scrollview:     override func touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view: UIView) -> Bool {
        if view.isKindOfClass(UIButton) {
            return true
        }
        return super.touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view)
    }

Comment: No problem and yes you are right you need that function. I will edit and foreel free to accept the answer.